# Conditional summing in R

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

just a bit stuck with this - I'm after something to help me sum values in $A, but only those values correspond to the 0's and the FIRST occurrence of a 1 in $B. I used the below code to previously sum the first occurrence of a value, and wonder if this can be adapted? If not I'm open to new approaches...Thanks in advance!

```
$A  $C
1   0
1   0
1   1
1   0
1   1
1   0



 DT <- data.table(data)
     DT[ ,B1 := {   bb <- rle(B==1)  
     r <- bb$values r[r] <- seq_len(sum(r))  
     bb$values <- r   inverse.rle(bb) } ]

   DT[B1 == 1, sum(A)]
```

Comment: The function duplicated is useful for finding the first occurrences of a value within a data.frame or vector. Returns a vector of the same length as input consisting of TRUE/FALSE. TRUE means it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DT[ !duplicated(C) | C == 0, sum(A) ]
```

In the comments it was remarked that was really wanted was the sum of `A` up to and including the first occurence of 1 in `C`. In that case:

```
DT[ seq_len(match(1, C, nomatch = 0)), sum(A) ]
```

If it were guaranteed that `C` always had at least one 1 then `nomatch=0` could be omitted.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - it works to an extent - but I believe it's because I didn't make the explanation clear enough - I need to stop summing $A once the first 1 in $C has been encountered. So all the 0's up to and including the first 1, ignoring values corresponding to later 0's -  Does that make sense?